# Mock a method call from another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, stubbing

My code structure :

```
class A {
    void methodA() {
        //some code
        B b = new B();
        response = b.methodB(arg1, arg2);
        //some code using "response"
    }
}
```

I am UNIT testing class A and don't want to actually call methodB(). Is there any way to mock this method call by a custom response. 
I tried Mockito to mock this method call as below:

```
B classBMock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
Mockito.when(classBMock.methodB(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(customResponse);
A objA = new A();
objA.methodA();
```

On calling methodA() the above way I don't get customResponse when methodB() is called within A. But when I call methodB() with classBMock, I get the customResponse.
Is there anyway I can get customResponse from methodB() while calling methodA().

Answer (score 4):

One common way of doing this is extracting the creating of the collaborator instance to a method, and `spy`ing the class you want to test.

In this case, you could rewrite `A` like this:

```
public class A {
    public B createB() {
        return new B();
    }

    public void methodA() {
        //some code
        B b = createB();
        response = b.methodB(arg1, arg2);
       //some code using "response"
    }
}
```

Now your test can `spy` the `A` instance you're testing, and inject a mock for `B`:

```
B classBMock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
Mockito.when(classBMock.methodB(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(customResponse);
A objA = Mockito.spy(new A());
Mockito.when(objA.createB()).thenReturn(classBMock());
objA.methodA();
```

**Edit:**

If you cannot modify `A`, another way to go could be to use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock). Note that this code snippet shows only the relevant mocking, and doesn't display the annotations required to allow PowerMock to instrument your class:

```
B classBMock = Mockito.mock(B.class);
Mockito.when(classBMock.methodB(arg1, arg2)).thenReturn(customResponse);
PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(classBMock);
A objA = new A();
objA.methodA();
```

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik. That's a possible solution but as I can't change the original source code, is there any way of doing it without any code modification ?

Comment: @user2393393 One option is PowerMock, although, personally, I'm not a fan. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik. That serves the purpose. Is there any reason you won't prefer PowerMock ? Just asking if there's something I should know.

Comment: @user2393393 PowerMock uses bytecode instrumentation, which is usually has a considerable performance impact on your tests, and may be dodgy if your code isn't straight forward and involves reflection, or other byte code manipulation techniques